# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error ORA-06512: at "test.BITOPS2", line 68

Tags: oracle, plsql

While running 
`SELECT BITOPS2.BITAND(128,64) FROM DUAL` , I am getting the below error

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
>   ORA-06512: at "test.BITOPS2", line 68

(Happens only when i use number 128 )

Comment: I suggest you look at the bitops2.bitand function and see what it's doing. That doesn't sound like a built in function (although there is a built-in BITAND function which works perfectly well for those two values, in 11.2.0.4).

Comment: @Boneist I think the op is referring to this function: http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/faq/bitwise.html which produces strings

Comment: But it's strange that schema you're referencing (BITOPS2)... isn't there a user function there?

Comment: @vc74 That would be ... positively ancient! I hope the OP isn't still stuck with an 8i database!

Comment: @vc74 we are exactly referring to that package which u have shared in that link.....we face error while using the number 128 only  (SELECT BITOPS2.BITAND(64,128) FROM DUAL)

Comment: Presumably you are using the longer version of the `bitops2` package on that page, as the first one doesn't have 68 lines. We shouldn't have to guess what code you are running, though.

Comment: @aruns Can you not use the default BitAnd function?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the Bart Pots version of this package from circa 2001 from http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/faq/bitwise.html, there seems to be a bug in `bitops2.raw_ascii` such that it returns `null` for values 128 to 255. This means the loop defined as:

```
for nr_pos in utl_raw.length(v_tmp_raw1) + 1 .. nr_diff_length loop
```

is in effect

```
for nr_pos in null .. null loop
```

hence your ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error.

The bug is rather interesting. Here's the function:

```
function raw_ascii(p_dec number) return raw is
    v_result varchar2(1999);
    v_tmp1   number := p_dec;
begin
    loop
        v_result := chr(mod(v_tmp1, 256)) || v_result;
        v_tmp1   := trunc(v_tmp1 / 256);

        exit when v_tmp1 = 0;
    end loop;

    return utl_raw.cast_to_raw(v_result);
end raw_ascii;
```

If you pass `128`, then `mod(128,256)` = 128. `chr(128)` is a single character, but `chr(128) || null` is null. I'm not really sure why.

As vc 74 suggested, why not just use the built-in `bitand` function?